# Getting null when try to access the json dataC++

Tags: c++, json

From an HTTP POST response, I retrieve a `JSON`

Now, I would like to get the value of the `first parameter` in the JSON
which is an integer with a value of 1

```
std::string postDatac = "{\"PayloadType\":1,\"TestType\":0,\"IssueDate\":\"270419\"}";

           Json::Value root;
           Json::Reader reader;
           bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( postDatac, root );
           if ( !parsingSuccessful )
           {
               std::cout << "Error parsing the string"  ;
           }

           const Json::Value code = root["PayloadType"];

           for ( int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++ )
           {
               // Print the values
               std::cout << code[i]  ;

       }
```

`https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp/tree/master/vendor/jsoncpp-0.10.5/dist/json`. I used the JSON library from this project

When I try to debug the code, the variable **code** keep getting null, could anyone please point out what I did wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp . I used the json library from this project

Comment: Did you inspect the root object in the debugger ? operator[] seems to create a null object if it can't find a value with that name. Check which values are available, if any ?

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: bool

  parse(const std::string& document, Value& root, bool collectComments = true);

Comment: @epiphany, what does `root.isObject()` return?

Comment: @epiphany Have you tried to dump all elements which got parsed (Value::getMemberNames())?

Comment: no overloaded function takes 1 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const Json::Value code = root["PayloadType"];`

`code` is an `intValue` which can be found by using `code.type()` which returns `1` that is mapping to  `enum ValueType::intValue`.

`code.size()` returns `0` if the `Value` is not `arrayValue` and shouldn't even enter the for loop (which is happening in my case).

If you want to read the integer from `code`, just use

`std::cout<< code.asInt() <<std::endl;`

which should give the output `1`.